# How to write rspec for index action of api controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I run this spec it always give nil object, can anyone help me out here.

```
 require 'spec_helper'

   describe Api::SongsController do
    describe "GET index" do
     it "assigns songs json" do
      song = Song.create(:title => "song")
      get :index, :format => :js
      assigns(:songs).should eq([song])
      end
     end        
   end
```

And my controller code

```
     def index
      songs = Song.all
      if !songs.empty?
       respond_with songs
      else
       render :json => {:message => "No songs found."}
      end
     end
```

Comment: what is the error that you're getting?  what line does it reference?

Comment: After the running the spec, expected has song instance but got has nil. So basically it is not passing the test. Basic matcher test.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should have the instance variable. So change

```
 def index
  songs = Song.all
  if !songs.empty?
   respond_with songs
  else
   render :json => {:message => "No songs found."}
  end
 end
```

to

```
 def index
  @songs = Song.all
  if !@songs.empty?
   respond_with @songs
  else
   render :json => {:message => "No songs found."}
  end
 end
```

That should do :)